# check what html document is loaded into iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a sprymenu on my html page that loads other html files into an iframe.  I want to be able to change some text above the iframe to tell what the html file is. I was thinking that what I would do is check to see which html file is in the iframe with this:

```
if (!$("#myframe").text=='Rock.html' {!$("#CurrChart").innerhtml="Rock Type Charts";}
```

CurrChart is a paragraph with the id of CurrChart. 
myframe is the iframe that is where the html loads.

This code doesn't work.

But I feel there must be an easier way...

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the `src` attribute...

```
$("#myframe").attr("src");
```

That will be the full url of the iframe address.

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery, access to the iframe contents.

```
if ( $('#myframe').contents().find('#someID').html() == 'Rock.html' ) {
    ...
}
```